# how do i get the name of the google docs file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to take the file name of "google docs" and insert it into the document.

[Image GoogleDocs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvDE2.png)

Whenever it is changed it must also be changed within the document.

Inside google docs I can't find the possibility to insert the filename field.

how can I do ?

Comment: I think that `I need to take the file name of "google docs" and insert it into the document.` can be achieved. But, about `Whenever it is changed it must also be changed within the document.`, in your situation, how is the filename of the document changed? If it is changed by a script, you can achieve your goal by modifying the script. But, if it is manually changed, as a simple method, how about checking the filename using the time-driven trigger? But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, if those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onOpen() {
  Logger.log(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName());
}
```